# Changing a string variable inside a FISH function to be used as an input into a FLAC analysis via a FLAC command

Tags: flac

I am creating an embankment dam model using FLAC and I am attempting to automate the material property input.  There are 3 materials.  I have a list of density variables defined in a previous FISH function as so: _d1 = 3.5, _d2=3.6, and _d3= 3.7.  The number 1, 2, and 3, correspond to a different material within a FLAC model.  I want to loop through the materials and the variables and input the appropriate density for each material.

I imagine it will involve looping through the materials and then making a string into a floating point variable somehow.

All I have so far is

```
;FLAC commands

ini ex_1=1 group='material 1'
ini ex_1=2 group='material 2'
ini ex_1=3 group='material 3'
;and:
def setup
numberof_mats = 3
end
setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that loops through each material, then through each zone, and when the material number you are looping through is equal to the zone you are looping through you can assign the variable by making a string variable that changes with the looped material number, to be used in the prop command via the rez_exe command.  There is probably an easier way to do this, but:

```
def _assign
loop _n(1,numberof_mats)
loop i (1,izones)
loop j (1,jzones)
if ex_1(i,j)= _n
_xx=i
_yy=j
_d_string=string('_d')+string(_n) ;Creates str var that changes with _n loop
_d_float=parse(_d_string,1) ;converts string to a regular var, float here.
_aa=rez_exe('prop d=_d_float i _xx j _yy') ;_aa could be any variable
endif
endloop
endloop
endloop
end
_assign
```